# R placing rugarch output into a dataframe

Tags: r

I have updated to the last version of R and updated the rugarch package as well.
Unfortunately some code that worked previously no longer works. I now get an error.
I would be greatful for some help to get the output into a dataframe.

```
library(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)
spec = ugarchspec(  )
fit1 = ugarchfit(spec =  spec, data = sp500ret)
df.fit1 <- as.data.frame(fit1,which="VaR")

Error in as.data.frame.default(fit1, which = "VaR"): 
cannot coerce class "structure("uGARCHfit", package = "rugarch")" to a 
data.frame 
attributes(fit1)
```

shows:`$fit$sigma`

but when I try:

```
df1 <- data.frame(fit1$fit$sigma)
```

I get an error message;

```
Error in fit1$fit : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. as.data.frame(fit1, which="VaR") NEVER worked with an object of class uGARCHfit (you are confusing this with a uGARCHroll object). If you want the conditional VaR you can NOW (in the new version) use the quantile method e.g. quantile(fit1, c(0.01,0.05)).
2. If you want the conditional standard deviation then you should use sigma(fit1) which will return an xts matrix, or fit1@fit$sigma (@ goes after an object in S4 classes). This and most other questions can be answered by carefully reading the documentation, vignette and the author's website which contains details of the changes.